# Create list of strings

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have list of strings

```
field :: [String]
field = ["......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......",
         "......"]
```

But it is static. I am trying to write function, that take two numbers (length of one string X and number of all strings Y).

```
createField :: (Int, Int) -> [String]
```

For example: 
`createField 4, 5`

It should return this

```
["....",
 "....",
 "....",
 "....",
 "...."]
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: The function [`replicate`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=replicate) may be of use to you. Really though, you should make an attempt and ask about any issues that arise with that, rather than just asking for a solution.

Comment: first of all, it's `createField (4, 5)`. second, can you write what `createField (4, 1)` should return? or even `createField (4, 0)`? do you see how to get the former from the latter? and then `createField (4, 2)` from `createField (4, 1)`? can this be generalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not wrong, using a 2-tuple for parameters is not very common. It is more *Haskell-ish* to write a function with signature:

```
createField :: Int -> Int -> [String]
```

you can then invoke this with `createField 4 5` for example.

You can make make use of [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) here, both to construct the `String` *and* the list of `String`s. For example:

```
GHCi> replicate 4 '.'
"...."
```

I leave it as an exercise to construct the list itself. The function will be of the form:

```
createField :: Int -> Int -> [String]
createField m n = _ (replicate m '.')
```

Where the `_` is something you need to fill in yourself.